# Clojure - Working with list and date-time

Tags: list, clojure, jodatime

I am quite stuck in this scenario.
I have a list of atoms representing bank transactions.

```
(#<Ref@29a71299: {:desc "DESC1", :amount 150, :date #<LocalDate 2017-01-10>}>)
(#<Ref@5a4ebf03: {:desc "DESC2", :amount 250, :date #<LocalDate 2017-01-10>}>)
(#<Ref@5a4ebf03: {:desc "DESC3", :amount -250, :date #<LocalDate 2017-01-11>}>)
(#<Ref@5a4ebf03: {:desc "DESC4", :amount 50, :date #<LocalDate 2017-01-12>}>)
```

I need calculate the balance account in the end of the day, so I should grab all transactions separated per day to know the balance in the end of the day.

Someone did it before ? What is the best way to filter dates and do this math ? I am still noob/student in clojure.

obs. I am using this library to work with date [Jodatime](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time)

Comment: Just loop over the list, and break every time the date changes.

Comment: You may also wish to use this clojure lib:  https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time

Comment: You mentioned you are using this problem to learn, how much of it do you want to work out yourself? How detailed an answer would you like?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks I will try.

Comment: @AlanThompson Thanks I will use.

Comment: @MauricioJunior I can write an answer if you'd like with an example. I was originally going to do it with `loop` since it should be fairly simple, but Arthur's suggestion using `partition-by` might work too. I've never used that function before.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt thanks for the advice, your answer for this question is perfect, I just need basic infos to know how to approach this problem, I am still learning and sometimes I spend to much time in one point because I don't know all good things clojure provides

Comment: @Carcigenicate let me try by myself first, I think is important try to improve my clojure skill. When I finish would be great if you could contribute with you knowledge, of course if you have time.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Otherwise, if you could provide an example using loop would be nice :) I can compare which one is easier for me.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt, could you add an example using (partition-by) for this scenario, I am trying but is quite difficult for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to break it down this way:

```
(defn per-day-balance [txns]
  (->> txns
       (partition-by :date)
       (map (fn [[{date :date} :as txns]]
              {:date date :balance (reduce + (map :amt txns))}))))
```

Find the daily balance assuming everyday starts with 0.  Sample run:

```
(def txns [{:date 1 :amt 10}
           {:date 1 :amt 3}
           {:date 2 :amt 9}
           {:date 2 :amt -11}
           {:date 3 :amt 13}])

user> (per-day-balance txns)
=> ({:date 1, :balance 13} {:date 2, :balance -2} {:date 3, :balance 13})
```

Now add a reduction function to get the running total.  The reduction function simply 'update' the cumulative balance:

```
(defn running-balance [bals]
  (let [[day-1 & others] bals]
    (reductions
     (fn [{running :balance} e] (update e :balance + running))
     day-1
     others)))
```

Sample run:

```
user> (->> txns
           per-day-balance
           running-balance)
=> ({:date 1, :balance 13} {:date 2, :balance 11} {:date 3, :balance 24})
```

*Note*: You can use whatever data type for :date field. Secondly, I deliberately avoid atom to make the functions pure.

Comment: Really appreciate for your help, I am almost finishing all code. Could you evaluate my code ? I think its important to know if I can improve ...

Answer (score 1):

A great way to approach problems in Clojure is to think:

1. How can I break this problem down (this is usually the hard part)
2. How can I solve each problem alone
3. How do I compose these solutions (this is usually the easy part)

Applying this to your problem I see these problems:

- segmenting a list of maps by a property of one of the keys

  `(partition-by ... something ...)`
- summing all the values of one of the keys in each of a sequence of maps

  `(map (reduce ...))`
- making an output format with the data and the sum from each segment

  `(map ... something)`

And the composing part is likely just nesting each of these as nested function calls. Nested function calls can be written using the thread-last maco and will look something like this:

```
(->> data
    (... problem one solution ...)
    (problem two solution)
    (some output formatting for problem three))
```

Comment: +1, but I'm not sure I agree with the "usually" diagnoses in the beginning. If you put off worrying about how to compose solutions, then you can often quite easily come up with a breaking-problems-down solution that's very easy, until you realize it's impossible to compose.

Comment: Really appreciate for your help Arthur

Answer (score 0):

This ended up getting more complicated than I thought it would. I looked at `partition-by`, and you should almost definitely use that instead. It's perfectly suited for this problem. This is just an example of how it could be done with a `loop`:

```
(defn split-dates [rows]
  (loop [[row & rest-rows] rows ; Split on the head
         last-date nil
         acc [[]]]
    (if row
      (let [current-date (last row)]
        (recur rest-rows current-date
          ; If the day is the same as the previous row
          (if (or (nil? last-date) (= current-date last-date))
            ; Update the current day list with the new row
            (update acc (dec (count acc))
                    #(conj % row))
            ; Else, create a new list of rows for the new date
            (conj acc [row]))))
      acc)))
```

---

```
(clojure.pprint/pprint
  (split-dates
    [[0 1 "16.12.25"]
     [2 3 "16.12.25"]
     [4 5 "16.12.26"]
     [6 7 "16.12.26"]
     [8 9 "16.12.26"]
     [1 9 "16.12.27"]]))

[[[0 1 "16.12.25"] [2 3 "16.12.25"]]
 [[4 5 "16.12.26"] [6 7 "16.12.26"] [8 9 "16.12.26"]]
 [[1 9 "16.12.27"]]]
```

Notes:

- This assumes the dates are in the last column, and that the rows are sorted by date.
- It returns `[[]]` when given given an empty list. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Really appreciate for your help @Carcigenicate